# Can one find in the writings of Ayn Rand a definitive list of rights?

Tags: ethics, rights, objectivism, ayn-rand, politics

Is there to be found anywhere in the writings, lectures or interviews of Ayn Rand a precisely-formulated list of rights, with or without justifications or explanations? In other words, did she ever set forth an explicit list or suite of individual / human / political rights?

For example, is there in her literature something like this:

RIGHTS

1. Life
2. Liberty
3. Assembly
4. Property

etc.

I know that she addressed and formulated rights in different works, but I would like to know if she ever set everything down together in one place.

Additionally, if such a formulation were to be made, would it properly belong to her ethics or to her politics?

Answer (score 3):

> **I would like to know if she ever set everything down together in one place.**

She did, in her book, *The Virtue of Selfishness*, essay *Man's Rights*. The essay is available in its entirety [here, at Ayn Rand Institute's website](https://ari.aynrand.org/issues/government-and-business/individual-rights).

To avoid from writing an essentially link-only answer, this is the most relevant bit:

> > A “right” is a moral principle defining and sanctioning a man’s freedom of action in a social context. There is only one fundamental right (all the others are its consequences or corollaries): a man’s right to his own life. [snip] The concept of a “right” pertains only to action — specifically, to freedom of action. It means freedom from physical compulsion, coercion or interference by other men.

---

> **if such a formulation were to be made, would it properly belong to her ethics or to her politics?**
>
> > “Rights” are a moral concept — the concept that provides a logical transition from the principles guiding an individual’s actions to the principles guiding his relationship with others — the concept that preserves and protects individual morality in a social context — the link between the moral code of a man and the legal code of a society, between ethics and politics. Individual rights are the means of subordinating society to moral law.